# LinearGradient doesnt't work on chartJs canvas for Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, html5-canvas, chart.js

Here I tried to add linear gradient on ctx object of canvas as usual.

```
    let canvas= $("#canvas");
    let ctx=canvas[0].getContext('2d');
    var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(250,174,50,1)');   
    gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(250,174,50,0)');
```

instead of using jQuery to access canvas object,I tried `document.getElementbyId` as well but didnt work either.
Chart is being printed just gradient is missing.I don't know why

Stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h83adp-chartjs-kfdgcy?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4vobe59a/) working demo

Answer (score 0):

You correctly created the `linear gradient` but forgot to assign it to the `backgroundColor` property of the `dataset`.

```
datasets: [{
  label: 'test',
  data: [100, 200, 300],
  backgroundColor: gradient // you need to do this
}]
```

Please take a look at your amended [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h83adp-chartjs-crjnu3?file=app/app.component.ts).